# Android, работа с alarm clock

Tags: android

Подскажите, возможно ли программно установить будильник на определённое время? Если да, то скиньте ссылку на пример, пожалуйста, или опишите как это реализовать.

P.S. реализация на Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent myIntent =  new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyAlarmService.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager =  (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 
pendingIntent);
```

Comment: а собственно класс MyAlarmService что должен содержать внутри себя??

Comment: https://blog.mikesir87.io/2013/04/android-creating-an-alarm-with-alarmmanager/

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение данного вопроса:

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM); 
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "New Alarm"); 
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hours); 
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, mins); 
startActivity(i);
```